# Is it possible to have two loggers with different nlog.configs?

Tags: c#, nlog

Lets say I have a programm that I dont controll. This programm allows me to build addins for it. I build an addin1 and addin2. Both use Nlog and have their own nlog.config files.Both are in their own solution and have nothing to do each other. The only similarity is that they both run in the same process and they both use nlog. What do I need to do so that they dont interfere. At the moment it looks like its random what config file is used. Probably depending on which addin is loaded last I guess?

If I only add simple log targets this leads to login in one file no matter what addin is actualy logging a message. If I use MethodCall it will throw an error if that class is not in both addins.

Its not really possible to share a nlog.config between those addins because they dont have to be both installed. It could also be that one isnt even mine and I have no controll over it.

Setting up the logger looks like this in both addins:

```cs
LogManager.ThrowConfigExceptions = true;
var basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
if (basePath != null)
    LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(Path.Combine(basePath, "nlog.config"));
else
{
    throw new ArgumentException(
        $"nlog.config not found! Make sure there is a nlog config definition.");
}
var logPath = Properties.Settings.Default.logPath;
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["logPath"] = logPath;
var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

nlog.config looks something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoreload ="true"
      throwExceptions ="true">

  <targets>
    <target name="logfileAddin1" xsi:type="File" fileName="${var:logPath}\addin1_${date:format=yyyyMMdd_HHmmss:cached=true}Addin1.log" layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message:withexception=true}" />
    <target name="logconsole" xsi:type="Console" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfileAddin1" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Each sub-component can have their own isolated LogFactory-instance. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-component-logging But adding plugin-isolation at very late stage will probably be a pain.